# TLS-handshake with own random numbers in Java

Tags: java, ssl, smartcard, handshake

I have a a piece of hardware which realises some crypto functions like random number generation (e.g a SmartCard). 
I would like to use this hardware during my TLS hadshake. Is it possible to do this, without implementing the TLS-Handshake by my own?

I tried to extend the class "SecureRandom" but the "next" methode is final so I can't override it so that it will return 'my' genetrated numbers.

So basically I would like to "outsource" all the crypto functions without implementing the TLS handshake in JAVA.

Thanks

Comment: What really matters for SecureRandom is the seed,The rest is predictable as algorithm is unchangable ,So i think maybe you can use your StarmtCard to generate random seed and use SecureRandom(byte[] seed) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend [`SecureRandomSpi`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandomSpi.html) instead. Then either implement a `Provider` or do a cheap `SecureRandom` as

```
  public MySecureRandom() 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
      super(new MySecureRandom(),null);
  }
```

(The implementation of `next` relies on the given SPI)

Then pass your `SecureRandom` as an argument to [`SSLContext.init`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html).