# TLS Handshake with a smartCard

Tags: java, key, smartcard, handshake

I still have some trouble with my TLS-handshake (see: [TLS-handshake with own random numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502544/tls-handshake-with-own-random-numbers-in-java)). The number generation works fine.

Now I have the problem, I need to generate the EC-keys and pre-master secret in my smartcard and use this keys for the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. I found the `KeyPairGeneratorSpi` which should do the job. But I do not know, how to use my own `KeyPairGenerator` during the handshake nor how to read the curve parameters and public key of the client which are sent during the "ServerKeyExchange".